# What type of microphone is suitable for cello together with a looper pedal?

Tags: recording, microphones, cello

I'm willing to buy for a friend a way for him to use a loop pedal (initially for an electric guitar) with his cello.

I really don't know much about sound recording with acoustic instrument... Would something like [K&K Pickups](http://www.kksound.com/pickups.php) do the job? What would be the differences between the single and twin ones?

I'm not looking for pro/semi-pro stuff, just a way for my friend to have fun playing over a loop.

Comment: I'd recommend a piezo pickup that can be attached to the bridge. Something like the Schatten C-12 Std. Cello Pickup. That's probably more expensive than you want, but something like that. It requires no installation or removal of the bridge, which are definitely traits to look for if it's just for fun.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the best type of pickup you can use for that is a piezo pickup. The type that you will attach to the cello (either on the outside or on the inside) and then you get from the piezo an electric signal that you can send to the looper effects pedal.

There are multiple brands that offer piezo pickups, some are better some are worst, you should just try out and see what you like best. Also note that positioning is key, if you put the pickup 10 cm to the left or the right or whatever, you'll get a very different sound.

Answer (score 0):

If you want high quality sound, the Realist pickup will simply plug into an amp and then you can plug the looper pedal. However, that one is kind of expensive. If you want something cheap that will do the job well, I recommend the Korg contact microphone. It is meant for plugging into a tuner, but it works excellently for plugging into an amp. You just clip it onto the cello bridge, plug the cord into your pedal, and plug your pedals into the amp. Hope this helps.